# Is there any problem with getting windows back-up to store system images somewhere on C: drive?

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore, windows-backup

I want to use the automated windows back-up function to create regular system images. C drive is the place where i have the most space, but something about it seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Backing up your system on the same hard disk is a bad idea. When your HDD gets corrupted for some reason, you won't be able to access your backups if you have put your backups in it. You should save your backups on a separate disk. Never put all your eggs in one basket.

Comment: if the drive failed i'd just start fresh, i just want the system image for if i stuff up something with some of my installed programs and i need to roll-back to before i messed it up.

Comment: In that case, you can save your image in `C:`.